# What is the best substitute for FlowDocument in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, hyperlink, markup, flowdocument

I'm porting an application from **WPF** to **Silverlight** and was saddened to [read](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/home?category=silverlight) of the **lack** of FlowDocument support.

**What is the best way in Silverlight then to display text with markup?**

I just need the basics, e.g.

- bold
- italic
- hyperlink
- colors
- font sizes

## Added:

I don't mean a RichTextBox (as in the [Vectorlight demo](https://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/demos/richtextbox)) but a way to format text **on the application surface itself**, like I can do with FlowDocument in WPF:

[image]
<sub>(source: [deviantsart.com](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/qna172.png))</sub>

Comment: confused by your edit - what does *on the application surface itself* actually mean?

Comment: e.g. not in a TextBox but in a TextBlock, i.e. not something that the user is supposed to edit, but just e.g. explanation text on the application

Comment: here I just posted a video ("How to easily put bold...") explaining what I mean here: http://tanguay.info/dpwpf

Comment: great way of showing what you mean. please see answer inline below.

Comment: The vector light demo shows the control being used to the full, however you should note that the toolbar etc is not part of the control, the basic control is just like a TextBox.  This inturn can be styled and set to readonly hence it is possible to create content that looks identical to the sample you posted.  However if I were doing this in SL4 I'd be looking at the RichTextBox rather than a free third-party item.

Answer (score 4):

In Silverlight 3 Vectorlight's Free [RichTextBox](http://www.vectorlight.net/demos/richtextbox.aspx) can do a pretty good job of what you need using HTML.

In Silverlight 4 you have the option of using the RichTextBox to represent your content.

Comment: Note that RichTextArea was renamed to RichTextBox in SL4 RC

Comment: @Timores:  Beta 2 has both, has the RichTextArea been dropped from the RC (I haven't got round to downloading it as yet)?

Comment: @Timores: Looking at the Docs it looks like it has.

Comment: I'm checking out the RichTextArea control in Silverlight 4, that looks promising: http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlight_sdk/archive/2009/12/03/have-you-checked-out-the-new-richtextarea-control.aspx

Comment: @Anthony, the breaking changes description mentions that RichTextArea is now called RichTextBox. See the end of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645049(VS.96).aspx

Comment: @Edward, I think that Anthony's answer is correct. The RichTextBox control accepts Paragraph content (like FlowDocument) and can be made read-only

Answer (score 1):

If you do get something like that up and running, msg me and maybe we can collaborate on bringing my "BindableFlowDocument" into the world of Silverlight. ;)

edit - wow, I must have gotten mixed up - my original answer was way off

Answer (score 1):

Inline with the comments of SL4 RC's RichTextBox (RichTextArea, circa SL4 Beta), and with your example of importing marked up text, the SL4 RC RichTextBox will allow for an import of XAML formatted text - like `string richText = MyRichContent.Xaml;` on this page: http://timheuer.com/blog/#richtextbox. Details are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.xaml(VS.96).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the RichTextBox in Silverlight 4.0