# Can't find reference FlowDocument

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I'm experimenting with a FlowDocument object but can't seem to get it work...

I keep getting the following error and have no clue what I should add.

> Error   5   The type or namespace name 'FlowDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What sort of project are you in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a reference to PresentationFramework dll to your project.

Add `using System.Windows.Documents` to your source file.

Note that FlowDocument is not included in Silverlight.

Comment: Any idea how it can be added to a silverlight project :/?

Comment: Nope. I believe FlowDocument was cut from Silverlight in part to slim down the Silverlight deployment size but possibly also because core WPF features were cut from Silverlight that FlowDocument requires.  Shop around for third party equivalents. Probably not a good use of your time to reimplement FlowDocument yourself.

Comment: First hit in Google for "Silverlight flowdocument" : http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/Introduction-to-FlowDocument-for-Silverlight.aspx

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456728/what-is-the-best-substitute-for-flowdocument-in-silverlight